# Calculate Days in Month For Leap Year

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Sorry for another date related question but I could not find a post that addressed this. 
I am trying to add a column to my date table that shows the # of days in each month, and have that handle for Leap year - below is my progress:

```
case when
Date like '01%' then '31'
Date like '02%' and  then ''
Date like '03%' then '31'
Date like '04%' then '30'
Date like '05%' then '31'
Date like '06%' then '30'
Date like '07%' then '31'
Date like '08%' then '31'
Date like '09%' then '30'
Date like '10%' then '31'
Date like '11%' then '30'
Date like '12%' then '31'

end as DAYS_IN_MONTH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a date, then you can use:

```
select date_part(day, last_day(datecol))
```

Answer (score 0):

***-- Generating a Series with dates***

```
with base_table as 
(
select
  dateadd(day, '-' || seq4(), current_date()) as dte
from
  table
    (generator(rowcount => 1095))
  )
```

***-- Count the days in month after grouping it***

```
SELECT count(*) as days_in_month,
         date_trunc('Month',dte) as month
  FROM base_table
  -- Filter here for necessary days
  where dte between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
  GROUP BY 2
```

***--  Join this table with your table***

Comment: Thanks for this but I think the code approved above your response is pretty adequate. Any reason why you think your code is superior ?